# Java ExplorerManager Filter

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, filefilter

I have implemented https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/file-browser to show only folders (changed == in accept() to !=).  However, no matter what I have done it only calls the FileFilterNodeChildren for the first level, the children of the root node.  So what I get is the folders of the root node (the directory I want) but it show ALL files and folders below this level.  I have put in statements that verify that the filter function is only called for the first level.

What do I need to do to filter the children of the first level and below?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're after. Do you want to only see the folders of the first level? Do you want to see folders only on any level? And did you step through your code with a debugger to see where it goes wrong? That's typically the best way to learn something about the code you copied.

Comment: I want to see only folders, at whatever level.  I do not want to see any files in this Explorer.

Comment: Note that the classes being used (e.g. `DataFolder`) are _not_ basic JDK classes and thus I can't help you with the specifics of that library. However, it seems that if you check for ` node.getLookup().lookup(DataFolder.class) != null` this might mean something different than "it is a folder". You'd need to read up on what `lookup` is doing to better understand what's going on. Just copy-paste won't help you in the long run.

Comment: Replying to Thomas: I put a breakpoint on the accept function.  For the four directories at the first level (below the root) the accept function is called twice.  That is, accept() is called for each of the four directories, then it is called again for each of the four directories.  It is not called for any of the files or directories below the first level directories.  I added a System.out.print for each of the node.getDisplayName() so that I could tell which directories it was being called on.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of createNodes() you need to wrap the child nodes with instances of FileFilterNode. Here is a revised version of createNodes():

```
@Override
protected Node[] createNodes(Node object) {
    List<Node> result = new ArrayList<Node>();
    for (Node node : super.createNodes(object)) {
        if (accept(node)) {
            // This is the only changed line
            result.add(new FileFilterNode(node));
        }
    }
    return result.toArray(new Node[0]);
}
```

This was tested in NetBeans 8.2 on Windows and works as expected. The "File Browser" displays a tree containing only folders at all levels.

Comment: Okay, this works to get the filter called for nodes below the first level.  However, when I try to filter out non-directory nodes (i.e.: files) then it causes other problems.  These problems are difficult to describe and are better experienced.

I will be using jtree instead of bean tree because it allows me to build the tree instead of it building the tree.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: I tested it on Windows with NetBeans 8.2 just now and it seems to work fine. I'm curious what the other problems are.

Comment: I just tested it on Linux using NetBeans 9.0.1.  When I expand the final directory it "silently" throws an exception.  (i.e.: I see the exception information in the debugger but not in the GUI.)  On all others when I expand it I see a "blank" document for each of the files filtered out, an exception is thrown in the debugger for each and every one of those files, then when it is done with this (because throwing the exceptions takes time) the "blank" documents disappear and the tree appears how I expect it to be.  By "blank" I mean that the document icon is shown with no name.